# Start a longtable in Latex at top of next page

Tags: floats, longtable, afterpage

I want to use the `longtable` environment for a table. However, I do not know how to place it at the top of the next page, as I can do with the `table` environment. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the `afterpage` package and its command `\afterpage` to defer typesetting of the `longtable` environment to the top of the next page.

```
\documentclass{article} % or whatever document class you use
... % rest of preamble
\usepackage{afterpage}  % load the afterpage package
\usepackage{longtable}  % load the longtable package
\begin{document}
... % stuff
\afterpage{%
   % Contents of "longtable" environment:
   \begin{longtable}
   ...
   \end{longtable}
}% end of scope of afterpage directive 
... % remainder of document
\end{document}
```

Comment: `afterpage` always renders the table in the next page. `table` environment behave a little bit different as it a a float environemt. As the major difference between a `longtable` and a `table` is the spacing. Therefore, I found another solution to make a `table` look like a `longtable`: add the command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` inside the `table` environment.

Comment: @AnCongTran - Thanks for providing this clarification. I had gone by the question in the original posting, viz., how to place [a longtable environment] at the top of the page. I see now that you want to make a `table` (and its `tabular` environment, right?) look like a `longtable`.

Comment: I have the opposite problem: my longtable starts at the top of the next page, but I want to start it straight away. What is the opposite of `\afterpage`?

Comment: @ChrisPeh - How close are you to the bottom of the page when the `longtable` environment starts? How large is the longtable's header, i.e., how many rows does it have?

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your clarifying questions. No header, but a list of options - therefore table format. I tried it at top of page (where it leaves a page blank, but takes the `/subsection` with it), then 3 lines of text down: Where it jumps to the next page after the `/subsection`, leaving 5/6 of the page blank. (I since found out that it does that when the first row is more than a quarter of the page (would still fit), because when I delete the first option, it doesn't do it...