# Starting a long table in a new page

Tags: longtable

I am trying to run the following longtable:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,booktabs,float,graphicx,longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[pt]{l C{3.5cm} C{3.5cm} C{3.5cm}} 
\caption[Average statistics]{Average statistics} \label{tab:sumstats} \\
\hline \hline \  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total variation} \\ \cline{2-4}
\textbf{Tests} & \textbf{Test 1} & \textbf{Test 2} & \textbf{Test 3}\\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{l}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} continued}} \\
\hline \hline \  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total variation} \\ \cline{2-4}
\textbf{Tests} & \textbf{Test 1} & \textbf{Test 2} & \textbf{Test 3}\\ \hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Note: aaa}\\
\endlastfoot

\textbf{Experiment 1} \\
A (\%) & 0.89 & 0.90  & 1.23\\
B (\%) & 14.25 & 14.31  & 14.76\\
C (\%) & 0.21 & 0.22  & 0.25\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However, I need this table to start in a new page and to fill the previous page with text.

Currently I can only put the table in a new page with \clearpage or \newpage, but I get an empty space in the previous page if I do so.

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113194/floating-longtable-in-latex/113205#113205

Comment: also do not put `longtable` in `center` it adds spurious vertical space but does not affect its horizontal position.