# Force a longtable on the top of / at the bottom of page

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, alignment

I would like to put a longtable on the top of / at the bottom of page, depending on what option is nicer for me.
If possible, I would avoid the use of `tabular` in my document for certain reasons.
Note that `\clearpage` / `\newpage` is not a command which I would like to use to solve this problem.

My MWE, where `longtable` should be forced on the top of the second page, is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 

   \begin{longtable}{l l}
      1 & 2 \\
      3 & 4 \\
      5 & 6 \\
   \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your write-up is quite confusing, I'm afraid, especially the sentence "Can I do it somehow like with `[t!]` and `[b!]` in `tabular` environment?" Did you maybe mean to write `table` instead of `tabular`? For sure: for `tabular` environments, the `!` override is ignored, and the `t` and `b` position specifiers do *not* place the `tabular` environment at the top or bottom of a page. Your write-up also makes it sound like the entire `longtable` fits on a single page. If this impression is correct, why bother with the `longtable` machinery in the first place?

Comment: @Mico thank you for your feedback. My goal is to fit the beginning of a **longtable** to the top of the page. My table does not fit necessarily on a single page, but a one-page display may not be exluded. This is why I insist on `longtable`.

Comment: as far as I can tell, you want `\clearpage` before the `longtable`

Comment: As far as I know, a longtable does not float and is inserted where it is used in the code. Depending on the actual document, your could however probably make  make use of the `\afterpage` command from  the `afterpage` package. This is also explained here: [Longtable float placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215436/134144) and here: [Start a longtable in Latex at top of next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113194/134144)

Comment: why not use blank (phantom rows) at the beginning of the table--the number of phantom rows to be added can be customised through a separate `\newcommand`